# 'Stream Closed' error when using s3distcp to copy files from HDFS to Amazon S3

Tags: hadoop

I am using s3distcp to copy files from HDFS to Amazon S3. Recently, I started getting the 'Stream Closed' error for reducer tasks. I noticed that the error only happened where there were multiple threads (each thread assigned a single file to upload to S3) under the same reducer task. The reducer task fails on this error, but eventually succeeds due to the retries.

My initial analysis was that the threads were using the same instance of the FileSystem class. To avoid that, I used configuration.setBoolean("fs.hdfs.impl.disable.cache", true) before calling FileSytem.get to avoid getting a cached instance. But, I am still getting the same error. Here is a part of the syslog:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.read(DFSClient.java:2039)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient$DFSInputStream.read(DFSClient.java:1976)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:66)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager$RewindableInputStream.read(XMLEntityManager.java:2932)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:704)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(XMLVersionDetector.java:186)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:772)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:124)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:1163)
```

Another point that I should mention is that I recently moved from Hadoop 0.20 to Hadoop 0.20.205 and a new AMI (2.0.4). This issue started happening after moving to the new version.

I have been blocked on this for a while now. Any help or guidance would be helpful.